# Do EU Refund rules apply to Coronavirus related cancellations by airlines?

Tags: eu, cancellations, covid-19, emirates

I've got a flight ticket with Emirates, and as part of Coronavirus related cancellations, the Dubai -> Geneva leg has been cancelled.

I understand this does not lie under the EU flight regulations and hence Emirates is refusing a refund of the ticket, instead only offering a travel voucher or rescheduling.

The same ticket has a Paris -> Dubai leg which is not cancelled by Emirates yet. Hypothetically, if the Paris -> Dubai leg was to get cancelled, would EU flight regulations require them to (ignoring any additional compensation in the EU rules I may or may not be eligible for)

1. Do nothing
2. Refund 100% of the fare for Paris -> Dubai
3. Refund 100% of the fare for the entire itinerary

The overall itinerary is

Hyderabad -> Dubai -> Geneva
Paris -> Dubai -> Hyderabad

This was booked as a restricted refund fare and on the same PNR, if that matters.

Comment: please edit your answer, instead of adding notes as comment. On your hypothetical case: they may cancel the flight, but they may reschedule you to an other flight. It is difficult to answer an "hypothetical case".

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi , done. The hypothetical is for a situation where borders are shut, similar to how Indian borders are shut this week leaving no opportunities for near term (< 24 hours before\after) rescheduling

Comment: Now Emirates flight only to Switzerland, UK, and few other places, and not more in France, so we have the inverse case. Best way is still to contact them **friendly**, until you get what you think it is honest. From my experience you cannot argue to call centers (also if you were right): this should be done later on writing, but so note all conversation (and time).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, yes I noticed the news. I'm waiting for my itinerary to reflect the Paris flight cancellation post which I will try reaching out to Emirates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result here was that Emirates updated their policy, allowing 100% refunds for all COVID cancellations. This coincided with the cancellation of the remaining legs on my ticket which were not cancelled initially, hence I was able to leverage the Emirates policy and did not have to fall back on EC 261 rules to claim a refund.

The refund request was filed in the middle of April and the refund came through Mid July with a total deduction of about INR 1000 (which was less than 1% of the total booking amount)

Comment: Thanks for coming back and telling us how it worked out.